# How can I specify a d3.js selector using values from a data object?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js in a web application. The easiest method to describe what I'd like to do is to view the Fiddle linked below, but the basic setup is that I have an array containing data objects.

```
my_data = [{
    id: "B",
    text: "I want this text in B"
}, {
    id: "C",
    text: "I want this text in C"
}];
```

I want to add the "text" values in my_data to the appropriate `<div>` in the DOM, which are the ones specified by the corresponding "id" in my_data. That is, the DOM contains a div with id "B", and my_data contains an object with id "B", so I'd like to add the value of the "text" property to that `<div>`, say as a `<p>` element.

Now the question.

How can I write my d3 selector to use the "id" properties in my_data, without knowing
what values my_data will contain? (I.e., I don't want to hardcode them!) 
I'm using a dynamic data source, and my_data will frequently be
changing. I'd like to add the "text" property to the appropriate `<div>` using d3. 
It is guaranteed that the "id" properties in my_data will have a `<div>` with the same id
already present in the DOM.

Minimal example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Skq3/1/

Answer (score 0):

The selectors you pass to `d3.select` are just strings. So you can use the value of the property and *concatenate* it with other parts of the selector. For example:

```
d3.select('#' + my_data[0].id)
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, that gets just a single selection, so is the idea to loop over my_data, doing the selection for each element?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more D3 way to do it. The idea is to prepopulate the `div`s with data that you can then match your data array against to "filter" out the nodes you want. This is a bit contrived, but enables you to use D3's data matching to do the hard work.

```
d3.selectAll("div")
  .each(function() { this.__data__ = { id: this.id }; })
  .data(my_data, function(d) { return d.id; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
```

The `.each()` "binds" the data to the elements by getting their current IDs. This would usually be done through `.data()` in D3, but we have to hack it here as the elements exist already. After that, it's straightforward. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Skq3/2/).

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Lars' suggestion, but might be more efficient if you've got lots of `<div>`s on your page and only a small number are going to be manipulated.

First, select all `<div>` elements, then [filter that selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) based on your data array.  Then you're only working with the elements that you have data for.  It works a little faster with the data in a key:value object, but you could also use [`array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in your filter test.

```
var dataMap = {};
my_data.forEach(function(d){dataMap[d.id] = d;})

d3.selectAll("div")
  .filter(function(){ return !!dataMap[this.id]; }) 
      //returns true if the element's id is in the data
  .text(function(){ return dataMap[this.id].text; })
```

If you're going to be doing more complex things than just setting the text, you'll want to bind the data to the element with `.datum(function(){ return dataMap[this.id]; })`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a snippet using your sample and the tutorial at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

To just change the text you can make this call at any time.

`d3.select('#B').text('Now I want to B');`

Though if you want a more dynamic solution This function should help.

```
  function getObjByValue(myRoot, myType, myVal, newText){
    var d;
    console.log(typeof myRoot)
    if(typeof myRoot == "object"){
      for(d in myRoot){
        console.log(myRoot[d][myType])
        if(myRoot[d][myType] == myVal){
          d3.select('#'+myVal).text([newText]);
        }
      }
    }
  } 

getObjByValue(data, 'id', 'B', 'Now I want to B');
```

Which was adapted from https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/79be3b8c9e8b74549af5

```js
data = [{
    id: "A",
    text: "Hi From A",
    digit:12
}, {
    id: "B",
    text: "Hi From B",
    digit:8
}, {
    id: "C",
    text: "Hi From C",
    digit:15
}, {
    id: "D",
    text: "Hi From D",
    digit:42
}];

// I want to add the "text" values in my_data to the appropriate <divs>, which are the ones
// specified by the corresponding "id" in my_data.

// How can I write my d3 selector to use the "id" properties in my_data, without knowing
// what values my_data will contain? (I.e., I don't want to hardcode them!) 
// I'm using a dynamic data source, and my_data will frequently be
// changing. I'd like to add the "text" property to the appropriate <div> using d3. 
// It is guaranteed that the "id" properties in my_data will have a <div> with the same id
// already present in the DOM.



//From the tutorial at 
//http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/




//var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 4])
    .range([0, 42]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")

    .attr("id", function(d) {return d.id})
    .attr("name", function(d) {return d.id})
    .style("width", function(d) {return x(d.digit) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });




//From the tutorial at 
//http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/




//var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 4])
    .range([0, 42]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")

    .attr("id", function(d) {return d.id})
    .attr("name", function(d) {return d.id})
    .style("width", function(d) {return x(d.digit) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });


 
  function getObjByValue(myRoot, myType, myVal, newText){
    var d;
    console.log(typeof myRoot)
    if(typeof myRoot == "object"){
      for(d in myRoot){
        console.log(myRoot[d][myType])
        if(myRoot[d][myType] == myVal){
          d3.select('#'+myVal).text([newText]);
        }
      }
    }
  } 

getObjByValue(data, 'id', 'B', 'Now I want to B');
```

```css
#A {
    background-color: steelblue;
}
#B {
    background-color: red;
}
#C {
    background-color: green;
}
#D {
    background-color: orange;
}
#oldA {
    background-color: steelblue;
}
#oldB {
    background-color: red;
}
#oldC {
    background-color: green;
}
#oldD {
    background-color: orange;
}


.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="oldA" class="my_div">
    <p>Hi From A</p>
</div>
<div id="oldB" class="my_div">
    <p>Hi From B</p>
</div>
<div id="oldC" class="my_div">
    <p>Hi From C</p>
</div>
<div id="oldD" class="my_div">
    <p>Hi From D</p>
</div>

<br>
I want this text in B

<div class="chart"></div>
```