# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent if else statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, express

Although this seems to be a very common question - based on what I've read I can't see the problem with my code. Below you will see that I'm using return if the condition is satisfied so I would think that it wouldn't try and set headers with my else condition. Please take a look and let me know if there's something I'm missing here:

```
// get user by id
app.get('/api/users/:userId', function(req, res) {
  var userParam = req.params.userId;
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].id === userParam) {
      return res.status(200).json({user: users[i]});
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unless the requested user is the first element in the user array you are responding with a 404 before there is a match of a subsequent element. There are better ways to find a match in an array (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574113/how-to-get-the-specific-json-array-from-a-value-in-that-array/29574210#29574210)) but using your approach so far:

```
// get user by id
app.get('/api/users/:userId', function(req, res) {
  var userParam = req.params.userId;
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].id === userParam) {
      return res.status(200).json({user: users[i]});
    }
  }
  // No match in loop
  res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

Comment: Wow...I really needed a second set of eyes apparently - such a dumb coding mistake. Thanks for pointing it out for me.

Comment: It happens hence the concept of pair programming. :)